# How to use verilog $deposit with indexes

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

How can `$deposit` be used when the path includes the index from the `generate` loop.  When I try:

```
for(int idx=0; idx<`NUM_OF_ENGIES; idx++)
   $deposit(i_engines_array.engines_loop[i].engine_top.soft_reset_n, 1'b0);
```

I get the error:

```
Error-[STASKEC_IFAIDT] Illegal argument to $deposit task

  The first argument passed to $deposit task: path is illegal.
  Please pass net/reg/bitselect type to $deposit task and recompile.
```

Comment: Is `idx` a genvar?  Also, did you mean `engines_loop[idx]` instead of `engines_loop[i]`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to name the generate block and then you can index it.  See section 24.7 of the [standard](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).  For example:

```
genvar idx;
for(idx=0; idx<4; idx) begin : engine_loop
  engine engine_top();
end

initial begin
  $deposit(engine_loop[2].engine_top.soft_reset_n, 1'b0);
end
```